# How to add certificate to "MY" store for all the user account

Tags: c++, winapi, certificate

I am trying to add certificate to "MY" store in **C++ winAPI** but it only visible in current user. I made it as window service program which is running on **LocalSystem** mode.

But, I would like to add a certificate all the current logged on user accounts or all the user accounts

```
CertOpenSystemStoreA(NULL, "MY");
```

Refer: [certOpenSystemStore function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore)

How do I add certificate to all the user account through c++ code.